# SQL Query with Aggregate function on Left Join of One-to-Many Relationship

Tags: sql, join, aggregate, one-to-many

I have a one-to-many relationship where each user has many tasks, which are rated by difficulty. I want to query for a list showing each user once along with their most difficult task.

users table: user_id, username

tasks table: user_id, task_id, taskname, difficulty

I've tried a query like

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.username, t.task_id, t.taskname, MAX(t.difficulty)
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN tasks t ON u.user_id = t.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

However, I get the `not in GROUP BY clause` error when running this.

Comment: Your stated goal (show each user, and their most difficult task) cannot be done with a simple `max()` and `group by`, because it will show all task names for each user, and the maximum difficulty for each of those tasks.  What DBMS are you using?  How do you need to handle the situation where one user has two tasks that are both the same (max) difficulty?

Comment: see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03994e/1  
seems working fine

Comment: @Riad - the OP is using a DBMS that forces all non-aggregate fields in the `select` clause to also be in the `group by` clause, sqlfiddle isn't enforcing that restriction.  I suspect the OP is using SQL Server.

Comment: I am using MySQL. For the purposes of this question, I assume difficulty is unique per user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming one user doesn't have two tasks with the same max difficulty, you can do something like this.  Although, this isn't very performant.  It will work fine on a small dataset, but should be redesigned if your dataset is very large at all.  Hopefully it will get you pointed in the right direction.

```
declare @users table (user_id int, username varchar(10))
declare @tasks table (task_id int, user_id int, taskname varchar(24), difficulty int)

insert into @users values
(1, 'John'),
(2, 'Sally'),
(3, 'Sam')

insert into @tasks values
(1, 1, 'prepare grocery list', 1),
(2, 1, 'do shopping', 2),
(3, 1, 'cook food', 3),
(4, 2, 'do shopping', 2),
(5, 2, 'prepare grocery list', 1),
(6, 3, 'cook food', 3)

select u.user_id, u.username, t.task_id, t.taskname, t.difficulty
from   @users u
       left join @tasks t on u.user_id = t.user_id
where  t.difficulty = (
         select max(x.difficulty)
         from   @tasks x
         where  t.user_id = x.user_id
       )
```

This will be more performant:

```
select u.user_id, u.username, t.task_id, t.taskname, t.difficulty
from   @users u
       left join @tasks t on u.user_id = t.user_id
       inner join (
         select x.user_id, max(x.difficulty) as max_difficulty
         from   @tasks x
         group by x.user_id
       ) as y on t.user_id = y.user_id and t.difficulty = y.max_difficulty
```

Both of these queries return the following dataset:

```
user_id     username   task_id     taskname                 difficulty
----------- ---------- ----------- ------------------------ -----------
1           John       3           cook food                3
2           Sally      4           do shopping              2
3           Sam        6           cook food                3
```

If a user has two max tasks with the same difficulty, then the query will include two rows for that user.

Although, showing the query plan for this SQL says the 2nd query costs almost double what the 1st query costs.  Having `max()` in the `where` clause seems to take be more efficient than placing the `max()` in the `from` clause.  I would try it both ways on your real data, and see what the query plan/cost is for you.

Comment: Thank you. My data set is not very big, less than 1000 rows and less than 5 cols per table. I still went with the more performant solution for future-proofing.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you are looking for something like this

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.username, t.task_id, t.taskname,t.difficuilty
FROM users u LEFT JOIN tasks t ON u.user_id = t.user_id
INNER JOIN 
(
 SELECT user_Id,Max(difficuilty) D FROM tasks GROUP BY user_id
)Temp ON Temp.user_id = u.user_id ANDTemp.D = t.difficuilty
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    SELECT u.user_id, u.username, t.task_id, t.taskname, m.difficulty
      FROM tasks t
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT user_id, 
                   MAX(difficulty) as difficulty
              FROM tasks
          GROUP BY user_id) m ON t.user_id = m.user_id 
                             AND t.difficulty = m.difficulty
 LEFT JOIN users u ON t.user_id = u.user_id;
```